# Camera access in WebView in Java 8

Tags: java, javafx-8

I have a `WebView` in my JavaFX application that loads an `HTML5 file` that accesses the webcam of the local computer. It runs perfectly in Chrome and Mozilla but not in JavaFX's WebView. Is there a configuration that I need to set in order to run it in WebView? **Im using Java 8u60.**

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the WebKit in WebEngine does not support it:

With the following javascript:

```
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia 
        || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia || navigator.oGetUserMedia;
if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
    alert("getUserMedia supported");
    navigator.getUserMedia({video: true}, handleVideo, videoError);
} else {
    alert("getUserMedia not supported");
}
```

and this Java code:

```
    WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
    webEngine.setOnAlert(event -> System.err.println(event.toString()));
```

the output shows:

```
WebEvent [source = javafx.scene.web.WebEngine@3dd89471, eventType = WEB_ALERT, data = getUserMedia not supported]
```

I tried setting a confirm handler in case that the WebEngine tries to ask for permission, but that is never called.

Tried it with Java 1.8.0_66 on OSX 10.11.